# dynamic number of file upload - PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm creating a page when user can enter how many files he want to upload then that page is rendered again with a form, after submission to another page the files are uploaded.
But i'm receiving an error [if i upload 1 file, else the problem is userfile[limit-1]]
`Notice: Undefined index: userfile0 in E:\wamp\www\uploader\uploader.php on line 10`

I'm pasting here my code
**index.php**

```
<html>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['num']) && !empty($_POST['num']))
{
?>
<form name="uploader" action="uploader.php" method="post">
<table>
<tr><td>Title</td><td>Select File</td><td>Description</td></tr>
<input type="text" name="number" value="<?php echo $_POST['num']; ?>"/>
<?php
for ($i=0;$i<$_POST['num'];$i++)
 echo '<tr><td><input type="text" name="title'.$i.'"/></td>
           <td><input type="file" id="userfile'.$i.'" name="userfile'.$i.'" size="30"></td>
           <td><textarea name="desc'.$i.'" rows="4"></textarea></td></tr>';
?>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="b" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<?php
}
else
{
?>
<form name="form" method="post">
How many files to upload ? <input type="text" name="num" value="1"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
</html>
```

**uploader.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['number']))
{
 for ($slot = 0; $slot < $_POST['number']; $slot++)
 {
  $title = $_POST["title$slot"];
  $desc = $_POST["desc$slot"];
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile$slot"]['tmp_name'],$_FILES["userfile$slot"]['name']))
   echo $name.' file Uploaded !';
  else
   echo ' file not Uploaded ! ';
 }
}
?>
```

`Edit`
SQL code removed

Comment: before clicking the _DOWN/CLOSE_ vote plz **mention your reason** !!!

Comment: Have you seen this manual page? [Uploading multiple files](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php)

Comment: It explains the build-in feature for multiple file uploads. Probably it helps as it offers to pass multiple files as an array, so you don't need to make the calculation and handle the indexes. Next to that on a related page, it explains that you need to have the multipart form data for it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your `<form>` tag, otherwise it cannot upload files/PHP cannot read it.

Answer (score 1):

You should also check the existance of a file before trying to upload it.

```
if (isset($_FILES['userfile'.$slot])) ...
```

Comment: the problem is PHP always says that $_FILES['userfile0'] does not exist, but when i viewed the HTML code it exist ! but thnx for your help :)